# Python MySQL blob datatype conversion

Tags: python, mysql

I use Python 2.7 to write data into MySQL blob column:

```
data_list=[{ id': 0, 'binarydata': 
'\x04\x0f\x002\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00 \x00\x06\x00@\x00\t\x00` 
\x00\x0c\x00\x80\x00\x0f\x0’}]  

cursor.executemany(SQL, data_list)
```

I want to read binarydata back from database in the same format as I put above:

I tried:

```
SELECT id, HEX(binarydata) as binarydata FROM T;
```

I got:

```
  data_list=[{ id': 0, 'binarydata': u'040F00320000000000030020000600400009..'}]
```

The difference is: binarydata now has prefix u' and all \x which were present in original data_list are gone.
Question: how to get data in original format (with \x and without prefix u')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python2.7 there is a builtin library `binascii`.

By using `binascii.hexlify` you can take `bytearray` e.g. `\x04\x0f` and convert it to hex value. By using `binascii.unhexlify` you can do it other way around.

```
import binascii

a = b'\x04\x0f'
b = binascii.hexlify(a)

print b  # '040f'
print binascii.unhexlify(b)  # '\x04\x0f'
```